# Javascript while loop callback

Tags: javascript

```
function jQueryFunction(url,callback)
{ 
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "GET",
        async: false,
        url: url,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonp: "callback",
        jsonpCallback: "tpsHandler",
        success: function(json)
        {
            return callback(json);
        }
    });  
}

function tmpFunction(callback) 
{
    var jsonArray = new Array();
    var i = 0;

    while(true)
    {
        for(var j = 0; j < url_array.length; j++)
        {
            jQueryFunction(url_array[j], function(json){
                jsonArray[j] = json;
                i++;
            });
        }

        if(i >= url_array.length)
        {
            return callback(jsonArray);
        }
        else
        {
            alert(i);
        }
    }
}
```

When I call tmpFunction the website keeps displaying "0" to me. Why is `i` always 0? Does tmpFunction never run the `for` loop?

Comment: Its asynchronous. A similar question that I responded to awhile back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14989827/why-does-this-javascript-array-print-out-0/14989861#14989861

Comment: You can not do while(true)! It is going start crashing

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here??

Comment: you should be using "deferreds" and `$.when` to look for execution of the final AJAX call...

Comment: Why do you want to create so many calls to the server at the same url through this recursive technique?

Answer (score 1):

From the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> By default, all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set this option to false. Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation. Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active. As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you must use the success/error/complete callback options instead of the corresponding methods of the jqXHR object such as jqXHR.done() or the deprecated jqXHR.success().

As shown above, you can't use jsonp with synchronous requests. So yes, your success callback is not getting executed (not even sure whether jQuery would trigger a callback if a function is synchronous in lieu of just return the value).

Furthermore, I suggest that you *never* make synchronous AJAX requests since network requests are long-running operations that can destroy user experience. Instead, take @Altinak 's advice and use Deferred objects.

Comment: And on a higher (yet slightly less related) level, be very careful of how you use this function. Whomever maintains the API servers that your constant network requests are thrashing is probably not going to be a happy camper :)

Comment: I believe you meant "never make _synchronous_ AJAX requests"

Answer (score 0):

Place the i after the jQueryFunction call.

Don't forget to place a "break;" after alert(i) to get out of the while loop.

If the i must be inside the callback in jQueryFunction call use a done to place your code to execute after ajax, and don't use i. Change async to true in the ajax call to get done to work.

```
$.ajax( //your settings
).done(function(data){
    //check the value in data instead of i.
    //due to .ajax being asynchronous code that needs to wait needs
    //to be in .done or the success callback.
});
```

Comment: the OP is using `async: false` - `.done` won't work unless he changes to `true` (which he should do, of course).

Comment: @Alnitak Whoops missed that. Changed the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution to this entire problem is to use deferred objects.

I'm going to ignore the `while (true)` bit for now, since that doesn't make sense:

```
function jQueryFunction(url)
{ 
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        async: true,                  // NB: **not** false
        url: url,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonp: "callback",
        jsonpCallback: "tpsHandler"   // any good reason why you're defining this?
    });  
}

function tmpFunction(callback) 
{
    var def = [];     

    for (var i = 0; i < url_array.length; ++i) {
        def.push(jQueryFunction(url_array[i]));
    }

    return $.when.apply($, def).done(callback);
}
```

This will run all of the AJAX queries in parallel (subject to per-host client connection limits) and once they're all done, `callback` will be invoked with each of the results (in submission order) in the `arguments` array.

NB: this isn't quite the same as your original semantics which has `callback` passed a single parameter that is the array of results.  If you want to keep that, use:

```
.done(function() {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 0);
    callback.call(this, args);
});
```