# javascript wait for several callback finished

Tags: javascript

I have a following javascript program：

```
                function jQueryFunction(url, callback)
                { 
                    $.ajax
                            ({
                                type: "GET",
                                async: true,
                                url: url,
                                dataType: "jsonp",
                                jsonp: "callback",
                                jsonpCallback: "tpsHandler",
                                success: function(json)
                                {
                                    return callback(json);
                                }
                            });  
                }

                var jsonArray = new Array();
                for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    jQueryFunction(url[i], function(json){
                       jsonArray[i] = json;
                    });
                }

                //process jsonArray
```

However, when I check jsonArray after the for loop, it is null. So my question is that how to store the return value from jQueryFunction to jsonArray in for loop and then process it?

I have tried $.when.apply($,jsonArray).done(function) but still the same, it is null.

Comment: You're passing a number as the URL, that might explain why it's blank?

Comment: Have you checked the return from something like Chrome's Developer tools?

Comment: Yes, callback(json) is correct. I just want to store them into a array

Comment: Possible Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19170391/javascript-while-loop-callback

Comment: Guessing someone didn't like the "use deferreds" answers

Comment: I also try deferred but still doesn't work

Comment: I only have used jsonp with a callback once and that was a while ago, so it's a big foggy for me. But have you tried sending the data as just json for a test? I don't see a tpsHandler defined as a function anywhere so I'm assuming you just didn't post it.

Comment: The reason I use jsonp is that json format cannot be displayed on highcharts correctly

Comment: possible duplicate of [Waiting on multiple asynchronous calls to complete before continuing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768293/waiting-on-multiple-asynchronous-calls-to-complete-before-continuing)

Answer (score 1):

A simple way:

```
function doTheAjax(url, callback) { 
  return $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    async: true,
    url: url,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonp: "callback",
    jsonpCallback: "tpsHandler"
  });
};

var reqs = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  reqs.push(doTheAjax(url[i]));
}

// send the array of requests to when, which will fire `done`
// when it's, well, done
$.when.apply($.when, reqs).done(function() {
  $.each(arguments, function(data) {
    // process the data
  });
});
```

alternatively, make a bunch of requests and put them into `jsonArray`, but keep 
track of how many you're making. When they all complete, you have the array. Create your
*own* deferred, resolve it yourself when the counter is up, and return the promise.

```
var getJSON = function(url) {
  var dfd = $.Deferred();
  var count = 0;
  var total = 10;

  var jsonArray = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
    doTheAjax(url[i]).done(function(json) {
      jsonArray.push(json);
      count++;
      if ( count >= total ) {
        dfd.resolve(jsonArray);
      }
    });
  }
  return dfd.promise();
};

getJSON().done(function(theCreatedJsonArray) {
  // do stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the answer to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19170391/javascript-while-loop-callback) (using deferreds) didn't work. But the cause of your problem is that you are checking the array before any of the ajax responses arrived. You also have a problem with `i` referencing the same value on all callbacks.

One simple workaround, if you know how many responses you're expecting:

```
var arr = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    jQueryFunction(url[i], function(json){
        arr.push(json);
        if(arr.length == 10) {
            // All 10 responses arrived!
            // DO STUFF FROM HERE
            // e.g., call another function
            console.log(arr);
        } 
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't think it will work. If I check the arr after the for loop, it must be null

Comment: You're not supposed to check it after the loop, see the comments in the code.